# mongodb: delete object within an array, nested within two objects

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to delete an object within an array.  But that array is nested within two objects.  How do I do this?

For example: let's say I want to delete the transaction with 
_id: 58c3154a19f82c0ddc53f0de

How would I do this??

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58bad6cf93ab9703da331e25"
    },
    "username": "david.lam@transfast.com",
    "password": "sha1$fc05ad7d$1$1cc86a287642516f947fda520ae8ddd42e983e23",
    "firstName": "David",
    "lastName": "David",
    "transactions": {
        "2017": {
            "3": [
                {
                    "where": "Duane Reade",
                    "what": "asdf",
                    "category": 6,
                    "amount": "34",
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "58c300ef1602f90c7166cbfb"
                    },
                    "date": {
                        "day": 10,
                        "month": 3,
                        "year": 2017
                    }
                },
                {
                    "where": "Amazon",
                    "what": "asdf",
                    "category": 2,
                    "amount": "100",
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "58c3154a19f82c0ddc53f0de"
                    },
                    "date": {
                        "day": 10,
                        "month": 3,
                        "year": 2017
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do so you need to use the [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator. Address array elements with the dot notation. The following query does the job:

```
db.user1.update({},
    {$pull: {'transactions.2017.3': {_id: ObjectId("58c3154a19f82c0ddc53f0de")}}
});
```